# How to Open iTunes Links inside Chrome for iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, google-chrome

My problem is that in my mobile website each time I put an iTunes Links it doesn't open inside Chrome for iOs see attachement below :

Link : https://itunes.apple.com/fr/app/candy-crush-saga/id553834731?mt=8

[image: ScreenShot from Chrome iOs]

How can I force Chrome iOs to open iTunes Links or is there a tips to bypass the problem?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in itunes server (note: see update) and I have replicated it here:  http://jsbin.com/umovad/latest

Basically Safari is intercepting itunes urls.  Unfortunately unless you use the correct URI scheme there is no framework in iOS to intercept the launch of a web page url, and in this case the default response by itunes is to return a JSON doc.

I have raised a bug here: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=261049

Update:  More feedback from the engineers,

> Summarizing briefly, this is a UA-sniffing bug on itunes.apple.com,
>   which appears to be looking for "iOS/" as a magic token,
>   and is catching our "CriOS/ because it ends in
>   "iOS/".  -- https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=242910

Answer (score -1):

Je pense que ton lien n'est pas le bon :/ essaye donc ça:
(I think you're using a wrong link, try this:)

http://itunes.apple.com/fr/linkmaker/

That can be helpful too:

https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/ios-links